# Java Sonar/FindBugs - Multithreaded correctness

Tags: java, multithreading, findbugs

Sonar reports following issue:

```
Multithreaded correctness - Method does not release lock on all
exception paths findbugs : UL_UNRELEASED_LOCK_EXCEPTION_PATH
This method acquires a JSR-166 (java.util.concurrent) lock, but does not release it on all exception paths out of the method. In general, the correct idiom for using a JSR-166 lock is:  



Lock l = ...;
l.lock();
try {
    // do something
} finally {
    l.unlock();
}
```

On this code snippet:

```
   public synchronized void put(T element) throws PreconditionException {
        Precondition.notNull(element, "Nullobject is not allowed");
        lock.lock();
        try {
            buffer[writeIndex++] = element;
            if (writeIndex >= capacity) {
                writeIndex = 0;
            }
            if (size.get() >= capacity) {
                // buffer is full
                readIndex++;
                lastOverflow.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
                if (readIndex >= capacity) {
                    readIndex = 0;
                }
                return;
            }
            size.incrementAndGet();
        } finally {
            try {
                notEmpty.signal();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

I won't get it, for what reason, this is not safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it shows that because if your code throws another subclass of Throwable (such as Error) on the line `notEmpty.signal();` then the lock won't be released.

You can argue that if there's an Error, your application will shutdown or that catching `Exception` is the right thing to do in this code. I do agree on that, but as FindBugs says, there are some code paths that end up in that lock not being released... and nothing stops a developer from extending Throwable :'(.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a finally for the unlock to make sure it is called, in contrast to a possible exception path that could lead out of your try-catch.

Besides, catching an exception and just logging it, should not be kept for production, as you surely are aware.

```
} finally {
            try {
                notEmpty.signal();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
               lock.unlock();
            }
        }
```